# Setting custom pushButton as cell widget consumes to much time

Tags: performance, pyqt4, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I have my push button that I set in `qTableWidget` column 9. It contains 3 values so when it's clicked it send signal with those values to my main that triggers `DoSomething()` method in my main. Problem is that this line consumes to much time `self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button)` . Here is code for my push button, and `PopulateTable()` method with output of the problem:

```
class MyPushButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2, value3, main):
        super(MyPushButton, self).__init__()
        self.__value1   = value1
        self.__value2   = value2
        self.__value3   = value3
        self.__main     = main
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self, QtCore.SLOT("triggerOutput()"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def triggerOutput(self):
        self.__main.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("DoSomethingSignal(PyQt_PyObject, PyQt_PyObject, PyQt_PyObject)"), self.__value1 , self.__value2 , self.__value3)
```

`PopulateTable()` method in my `class PYQTEmaszForm(QtGui.QMainWindow)`:

```
def PopulateTable(self, numberOfRows, rows):
```

## **EDIT 2 vvvvv**

```
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(10)
    self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoSelection)
    self.tableWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
    self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().hide()
    self.tableWidget.setVerticalScrollMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ScrollPerPixel)
#next line was the problem
    #self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Fixed)
    self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
```

## **^^^^^**

```
    self.tableWidget.setVisible(0)
    self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(0)
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numberOfRows)

    for i in range(0,numberOfRows):
        #I set columns 0-8 here like this self.tableWidget.setItem(i, colNum, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(rows[i][colNum]))  

        #here is my problem:
        button = MyPushButton(value1, value2, value3, self)# note that tose 3 values I can get only here, in a loop, so I must store them in my button that I use as link
        button.setText("Click to do something")
        startTime = time.time()
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button)
        print i," self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time: ", time.time() - startTime

    self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(1)
    self.tableWidget.sortByColumn(0,QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
    self.tableWidget.setVisible(1)
```

time to `cetCellWidget` grows for every line. Here is what i get for 325 rows:

```
0 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.010999917984
1 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.0119998455048
2 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.0130000114441
3 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.0150001049042
# ....
100 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.141999959946
101 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.134000062943
102 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.144999980927
103 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.151000022888
# ....
321 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.209000110626
322 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.211999893188
323 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.213000059128
324 self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time:  0.212000131607
```

So populating table lasts over 1 minute.

**My question is why `setCellWidget` needs so much time and why time is growing?**

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT1** I've tried setting simple `QPushButton` like this: `button = QtGui.QPushButton()`, and there is no difference in time consumption of `setCellWidget` method. So it doesn't depends on `MyPushButton` widget.

Comment: I tried testing the code in your question, and I cannot reproduce the problem. Even with 10 thousand rows, it only takes a few seconds to render. I've added a test script to my answer. Can you try it and confirm that it has the same poor performance for you? If it doesn't, the problem obviously lies elsewhere.

Comment: You pointed me in right direction... in other part of my code I have settings for table that I've added in EDIT 2 of my question. Commented line was the problem. It was probably resizing all rows to content, every time new row was added. So that explains previous time growth problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `setCellWidget` is just a convenience method: it is not optimized for adding hundreds of widgets to a single table, and so the slow-down in performance that you are seeing is inevitable.

To get the best performance, you will have to create a custom delegate and use `QStyle` to draw the button in its `paint` method. Of course, this also means you will have to implement all the mouse-handling and so forth yourself as well.

To give you an idea of what's involved, some example code can be found [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26916-inserting-custom-Widget-to-listview?p=128623#post128623).

**EDIT**:

Here is a test script based on the original code in the question. For me, this completes in a fraction of a second for 325 rows:

```
import time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyPushButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2, value3, main):
        super(MyPushButton, self).__init__()
        self.__value1   = value1
        self.__value2   = value2
        self.__value3   = value3
        self.__main     = main
        self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self, QtCore.SLOT("triggerOutput()"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def triggerOutput(self):
        self.__main.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("DoSomethingSignal(PyQt_PyObject, PyQt_PyObject, PyQt_PyObject)"), self.__value1 , self.__value2 , self.__value3)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Populate', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        self.populateTable(325)

    def populateTable(self, numberOfRows):
        self.table.setVisible(0)
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(0)
        self.table.setRowCount(numberOfRows)
        self.table.setColumnCount(10)

        for i in range(0, numberOfRows):
            for colNum in range(10):
                text = 'Text(%d, %d)' % (i, colNum)
                self.table.setItem(i, colNum, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(text))
            button = MyPushButton(1, 2, 3, self)
            button.setText("Click")
            startTime = time.time()
            self.table.setCellWidget(i,9, button)
            print i," self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(i,9, button) time: ", time.time() - startTime

        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table.setSortingEnabled(1)
        self.table.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.table.setVisible(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 300, 1000, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPDATE**:

I'm not sure *exactly* what you want, but the row resizing issue can probably be resolved by setting the resize-mode to `Fixed` before populating the table, and then setting it to `ResizeToContents` afterwards:

```
    ...
    self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Fixed)
    self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.Fixed)

    # populate table

    self.table.verticalHeader().setResizeMode(QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
    self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(1)
    self.tableWidget.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

Comment: can you explain to me why does it needs more and more time? It would be ok for me if time is always 0.010999917984 like when setCellWidget is used first time

Comment: @Aleksandar. I didn't look closely enough at your timings. The performance does indeed seem much worse than it should be. I should have tested things properly before answering. Having said that, I suspect the real problem may lie elsewhere. Can you please say what platform you are on, and what versions of Qt and PyQt you are using?

Comment: please take a look at EDIT 2, as I said in comment on my question -I've solved the problem, but how to properly resize rows to content now? `self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()` makes to much white space up and down, and doesn't update rows height when sorting is changed